# Using Terraform provider to add member to a predefined Azure AD Group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform

I want to use `azuread provider` in `Terraform` to add a resource into an `AzureAD Group` after the creation of that resource.

The script I am running in an `Azure Devops Pipeline` using the CLI and an Windows Agent.
For this we have of course a service principal dedicated to the DevOps who has the permission to add into that group. Running the terraform plan I am getting this error `'Error building AzureAD Client: Authenticating using the Azure CLI is only supported as a User (not a Service Principal).'`

The error is clear but is there any way to workaround this or am I missing someting? I can only use a Service Principal for this.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.56.0"
    }
   azuread =  {
      version = "~>0.8"
      }     
  }

resource "azuread_group_member" "example" {
      group_object_id  = "xxx-xxx-xxxxx"
      member_object_id = azurerm_data_factory.adf.id
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should add [service provider credentials into enevironment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret#configuring-the-service-principal-in-terraform). Refer to [this document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/guides/service_principal_client_secret#configuring-the-service-principal-in-terraform).

You could [use Azure CLI task with addSpnToEnvironment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops#task-inputs).

Use like this:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: "Terraform"
        inputs:
          azureSubscription:  shared-${{ parameters.environment }}-001
          scriptType: bash
          addSpnToEnvironment: true
          scriptLocation: inlineScript
          inlineScript: |
            export ARM_CLIENT_ID=$servicePrincipalId
            export ARM_CLIENT_SECRET=$servicePrincipalKey
            export ARM_TENANT_ID=$tenantId
            export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$subscriptionId
```